# How do ZFS snapshots work and how would I implement a retention policy similar to OpenSolaris'?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I've been using ZFS for a while and have snapshots piling up.

I believe I can start deleting the old snapshots, but want to be doubly sure.  A ZFS snapshot would be essentially similar to a git tag where it is a read-only reference to a point in time version of the repository.  The active data set would be HEAD and would remain unaffected if I delete a pointer to that point in time?

So, if that is the case, then if I want to have a 30-day retention policy, I can merely look at the creation date for the snapshot and discard anything > 30 days?

Are those assumptions accurate?

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty accurate.

Consider using the `sanoid` tool to automate the creation and destruction of such snapshots on whatever schedule you desire.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to checkout the sanoid project.